# useReducer with axios to pull data

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to properly trying to understand React.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD_STANDARD: 'add-to-compare',
  REMOVE_STANDARD: 'remove-from-compare'
}

function reducer(standards, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case(ACTIONS.ADD_STANDARD):
      return [...standards, addCompare(action.payload.standard)]
    case(ACTIONS.REMOVE_STANDARD):
      return standards.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.standard)
    default:
      return 'Nothing to add'
  }
}

function addCompare( standard ) {
  return axios
    .get("https://the-url.com" + standard)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)

      return {
        key: res.data.id,
        title: res.data.title.rendered
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

export default function EntryStandards() {
  const [standards, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  const addStandards = function(id) {
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ADD_STANDARD, payload: {standard: id}})
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9603)}>Add 9603!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9567)}>Add 9567!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9531)}>Add 9531!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9519)}>Add 9519!</button>

      {standards.map(standard => {
        return <p><button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REMOVE_STANDARD, payload: { standard: standard.id } })}>X</button> { standard.title } - { standard.version }</p>
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see, I have a button currently which has a hard-coded ID. When clicked, that button triggers a dispatch on a useReducer which performs an API data lookup using Axios against WordPress' Rest API.

If I console log inside the Axios return, I see the data. The return straight after where I create my object however simply returns an empty object into the reducer.

Is the dispatcher not able to use Axios in this way?

Is there a better way to go about this?

As always, your help is appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Did you try logging `res` and not `res.data`?

Comment: I did, yeah - res.data does see all of the data as I expect it, it just returns null in the actual returned object. Just using res does the same, but obviously with all of the wrapper data from Axios included.

Comment: And `res.data.title.rendered` does exist in your render right?

Comment: It does, I've console logged out that data individually also and in the console everything looks to be working.

Comment: Oh okay sorry I read too fast. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

`addCompare` is an async function. So you can't use it directly in a reducer as a reducer must return a result synchronously.

You may want to change your code to launch you request and then use the reducer to add the data like below:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD_STANDARD: 'add-to-compare',
  REMOVE_STANDARD: 'remove-from-compare'
}

function reducer(standards, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case(ACTIONS.ADD_STANDARD):
      return [...standards,action.payload.standard]
    case(ACTIONS.REMOVE_STANDARD):
      return standards.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.standard)
    default:
      return 'Nothing to add'
  }
}

function addCompare( standard ) {
  return axios
    .get("https://the-url.com" + standard)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)

      return {
        key: res.data.id,
        title: res.data.title.rendered
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

export default function EntryStandards() {
  const [standards, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  const addStandards = async function(id) {
    const standard = await addCompare(id)
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ADD_STANDARD, payload: { standard }})
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9603)}>Add 9603!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9567)}>Add 9567!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9531)}>Add 9531!</button>
      <button onClick={() => addStandards(9519)}>Add 9519!</button>

      {standards.map(standard => {
        return <p><button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REMOVE_STANDARD, payload: { standard: standard.id } })}>X</button> { standard.title } - { standard.version }</p>
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gabriel for your insight on async. It doesn't feel like a tidy solution, but I've ended up making the reducer store only the ID of the post, and then importing a new component that takes the ID and performs the Axios stage of mapping the data. Thanks for your help with this.